# JQuery Custom Plugin - AddClass Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a custom JQuery plugin, which will display an appropriate DIV block when an anchor element is clicked on.  For now, I'm calling the plugin "Content Slider".

I've managed to create the plugin and have got it working so that when an anchor element is clicked, the appropriate corresponding DIV is displayed.  However, I also want a CSS Class to be applied to the anchor element so it appears highlighted after it has been clicked.

See below for the HTML and JQuery plugin code:

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <a class="contentSliderTitle">Anchor 1</a>
    <a class="contentSliderTitle">Anchor 2</a>
    <a class="contentSliderTitle">Anchor 3</a>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div class="contentSliderContent">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="contentSliderContent">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="contentSliderContent">DIV 3</div>
</div>
```

JQuery Plugin:

```
   (function(){ 
    $.fn.contentSlider = function () {
        addClickHandlersToTitleElements();
        showContentDiv(0);
    }

    function addClickHandlersToTitleElements() {
        $("a[class=contentSliderTitle]").click(function () {
            showContentDiv($("a[class=contentSliderTitle]").index(this));
            return false;
        });
    }

    function showContentDiv(titleIndex) {
        $("div[class=contentSliderContent]").each(function () {
            $("div[class=contentSliderContent]").hide();
            return false;
        });

        $("div[class=contentSliderContent]").eq(titleIndex).show();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried adding code to the "showContentDiv" private function to remove a specified class (named contentSliderTitleSelected) from all of the anchor tags with the class equal to "contentSliderTitle" and add the "contentSliderTitleSelected" class to the anchor that was clicked on but this then stops the functionality in the "showContentDiv" function to work entirely, meaning that when an anchor is clicked, the displayed DIV does not change.

I'd be very grateful for some help with this as it is the first time I've tried to write a  JQuery plugin and I'm totally stumped!!

Thanks very much

Comment: There's nothing about this code that makes it work as a plugin. It just works straight up as a normal function. Tip: If you're not using `this` in the function creation call, it's not a dynamic plugin.

Comment: Since all references to elements (in this case the class names) are hardcoded, you could completely remove the `$.fn.contentSlider` wrapper function and it would make no difference at all to the functionality. Hence, not working as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Tim, your function should like this :

```
function addClickHandlersToTitleElements() {
    $("a[class=contentSliderTitle]").click(function () {
        showContentDiv($("a[class=contentSliderTitle]").index(this));
        $("a.contentSliderTitle").removeClass("contentSliderTitleSelected");
        $(this).addClass("contentSliderTitleSelected");
        return false;
    });
}
```

Hope this will fix your issue !!

Comment: Hi Kundan, thanks for your comment.  The code above doesn't seem to fix the problem.  I tried to add the 2 lines of code you added to the "showContentDiv" method as well but this didn't work either.  Any other ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @TimHarvey, i have prepared a demo for you. have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/b5c5A/

Comment: Hi Kundan, thank you very much for preparing the demo, it was very useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

The point of writing a plugin is that you can create as many instances of the plugin as you like on the same page. Yours will only work once on a page. Try something like this instead.

```
<dl class="contentSlider">
    <div id="left">
        <dt>Anchor 1</dt>
        <dt>Anchor 2</dt>
        <dt>Anchor 3</dt>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <dd>Content 1</dd>
        <dd>Content 2</dd>
        <dd>Content 3</dd>
    </div>
</dl>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With Javascript:

```
(function(){ 
    $.fn.contentSlider = function () {
        // Loop through each root element
        this.each(function() {
            // Save current element for later use
            var $root = $(this);
            $root
                .find("dt") // Find all titles
                .click(function() {
                    $(this)
                      .addClass("highlighted") // Add class to clicked element
                      .siblings("dt").removeClass("highlighted"); // Remove class from sibling elements
                    // Hide all descriptions under "root"
                    $root.find("dd").hide();
                    // Show only description on same index as title
                    $root.find("dd").eq($(this).index()).show();
                })
                .slice(0,1).click(); // Call "click" function on first "dt" element
        });
        return this; // return root element to enable function chaining
    }
})(jQuery);

$(".contentSlider").contentSlider(); // Run the function on all elements with the class "contentSlider"
​
```

Fiddle: ​http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9U6/3/

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your comment.  I understand your point about facilitating multiple plugin instances as it mentioned that in an MSDN post I read about creating JQuery plugins (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff608209.aspx).  Where in the code above would the code to highlight the appropriate <dt> element go (which is what I want the plugin to do as well)?

Comment: Inside the `click` function. Check my updated example and Fiddle.

Comment: and don´t forget to add return so you can keep using jQuery after you run the plugin.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks ever so much for your feedback - I've now managed to get my code to work :-)

Comment: Just one question - what do you mean when you say "you could return it when you do each"?  Is this something I need to add to the code or has it already been written?

Comment: He means that  since `.each()` returns `this` instead of writing `this.each(...); return this;` you can also write `return this.each(...);`. It makes no difference in this case, the two pieces of code will have exactly the same result.